# Eclipse exported Runnable Jar fails to locate external libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I have a Java Project with two external libraries. Everything runs fine in Eclipse, there are no errors when exporting as a runnable JAR. However, when I run my project through the command line using `java -jar myapplication.jar,` it throws the ever infamous `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no in java.library.path`.

I have tried using all three export options (extract, package, copy) with no success.

(using eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

In order for System.loadLibrary() to work, the library (on Windows, a DLL) must be in a directory somewhere on your PATH or on a path listed in the java.library.path system property (so you can launch Java like java -Djava.library.path=/path/to/dir).

Additionally, for loadLibrary(), you specify the base name of the library, without the .dll at the end. So, for /path/to/something.dll, you would just use System.loadLibrary("something").

You also need to look at the exact UnsatisfiedLinkError that you are getting. If it says something like:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no foo in java.library.path
then it can't find the foo library (foo.dll) in your PATH or java.library.path. If it says something like:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.example.program.ClassName.foo()V
then something is wrong with the library itself in the sense that Java is not able to map a native Java function in your application to its actual native counterpart.

To start with, I would put some logging around your System.loadLibrary() call to see if that executes properly. If it throws an exception or is not in a code path that is actually executed, then you will always get the latter type of UnsatisfiedLinkError explained above.

As a sidenote, most people put their loadLibrary() calls into a static initializer block in the class with the native methods, to ensure that it is always executed exactly once:

Comment: Ahh yes. I forgot to mention. The the libraries that I am using are OpenCV + ntcore. Both `ntcore.dylib` and `opencv_java320.dylib` are located in the generated jar. But for some reason the jar cannot seem to find my OpenCV library.

Comment: I have a similar problem, also with OpenCV. When I create the JAR file exporting from Eclipse, I cannot run the JAR outside my environment. I would like to create a JAR so that I can distribute it to anyone, including who does not have OpenCV installed. So, how can I create a JAR that includes all dependencies?